# Problem with using For..else loop in python 3 to print out even and odd numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a for else loop in python3 to print out odd and even numbers

Below is what I wrote:

```
for number in range(1, 20):
  if number % 2 == 0:
    print(f"even: {number}")
else:
   if number % 2 == 1:
     print(f"odd: {number}")
```

This was the results produced from above:

```
even: 2
even: 4
even: 6
even: 8
even: 10
even: 12
even: 14
even: 16
even: 18
odd: 19
```

How can I fix my original program to produce the following results:

```
even: 2 
odd: 3 
even : 4
odd:5 
etc.
```

Comment: you need to fix the indentation of your code, otherwise it is impossible to help you... (the second `if` is unnecessary...)

Comment: it is Identation problem ,just tab ```else block``` to be at the same level with ```if block```

Answer (score 4):

for/else loop works in a different manner than what you are assuming. Whatever you have tried may not the best way to print odd and even numbers though.  The `else` part gets executed when the loop didn't end because of a `break` statement. Upon a normal termination of the loop (that is, without encountering the `break` statement), the `else` part gets executed.

```
for i in range(1, 20):
    if i%2 == 0:
        print("even: ", i)
        break
else:
    #Do something
```

Here, after printing `2`, the loop will get broken and then the execution goes into the `else` part.

You can refer this for more information about [for/else](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
for number in range(1, 20):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(f"even: {number}")
    else:
        if number % 2 == 1:
            print(f"odd: {number}")
```

You just need to indent the `else:` to the same indent level as the `if` statement.
Also the second `if:` statement is unnecessary. You could change it to:

```
for number in range(1, 20):
        if number % 2 == 0:
            print(f"even: {number}")
        elif number % 2 == 1:
            print(f"odd: {number}")
```

If you still want the condition. `elif` works the same as `else: if:`.

Answer (score 0):

Python loops work with `identation` instead of `{}` you have to follow either `2 spaces` or `4 spaces`, so after every condition you have to indent your code.

there is no need to write another if you have only two possible scenarios so just put condition on first scenario and else to second scenario
Range excludes the last number,for you it should look like this

```
for number in range(2, 21):
    #indent of 4 spaces, now you have to write every logic inside this indent
    if number % 2 == 0:
        #another indent of 4 spaces 
        print(f"even: {number}")
    else:
        print(f"odd: {number}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#The problem is your spacing...

#the below code will yield the result you don't want:

for number in range(1, 20):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(f"even: {number}")

else:
    if number % 2 == 1:
        print(f"odd: {number}")

#By spacing everything from "else" down over
#one tab "else" (and converting it to an elif to save space) #is now considered alternative
#to the above if statement:

for number in range(1, 20):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(f"even: {number}")

    elif number % 2 == 1:
            print(f"odd: {number}")
```

Comment: You can add `else:` clauses to for loops in python. OP has specifically mentioned that they are using the `for/else` construct.

Comment: Yes but if you notice in his code he wrote else followed by an if. An elif achieves something similar to how he was thinking his code through.

Answer (score -1):

Correct Code.
Python teaches you indentation a lot.

```
for i in range(1,20):
    if i%2 == 1:
        print("odd: ",i)
    else:
        print("even: ",i)
```

Comment: The question is regarding `for/else` loop structure and not about printing odd and even numbers in the range of 1 to 20.

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan That's why i wrote about indentation.Gave him a snippet of indented code also.

Comment: Yes, I have given it in my answer.

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan Then why the comment?